# System.TypeInitializationException occurs

Tags: entity-framework

I've started to learn Entity Framework recently and I'm new. I wrote the first simple program, but it doesn't work. I tried to find solution on Google, but without result. I hope to find answer here.

ApplicationContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace HelloApp
{
    class ApplicationContext: DbContext     
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }     

        public ApplicationContext()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)   
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=helloappdb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace HelloApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
            {
                User user1 = new User { Name = "Tom", Age = 33 };
                User user2 = new User { Name = "Alice", Age = 26 };

                db.Users.Add(user1);
                db.Users.Add(user2);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully saved!");

                var users = db.Users.ToList();
                Console.WriteLine("List of objects:");
                foreach (User u in users)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{u.Id}.{u.Name} - {u.Age}");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!!!

[Update] I realised that System.TypeInitializationException clarifies me, what problem happened:

```
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper' threw an exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Failed to load C:\Users\Босс\Desktop\x86\SNI.dll
```

I was looking for on Google, but could find only one posibble explanation:

```
"That makes me suspect that you build it on a 64 bit system and then just transferred the files to the other machine. You need to publish the project for an x86 target to get the right native dependency resolved. Give it a try."
```

I have 64-bit Windows 10 on 64-bit CPU and i can't understand how to publish my project in another bit rate?

Comment: The .Net version of your app, that's what matters.

Comment: @GertArnold .NET Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it can sound ridiculous, but all what i need was updating of NuGet package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient